# WordPress widget plugin image not displaying (garbled code shows instead)

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to fix a plugin problem on a friend's website. The plugin widget should display x2 images & some links but on my friends website the images show as garbled code.
I cannot find answers to what is causing this.

The problem code is seen at
[exploreinternetmarketingonline](http://exploreinternetmarketingonline.com)

How it should display is seen @
[onlinewpthemetest](http://www.onlinewpthemetest.richard-dickinson.com)

I have tried deleting all plugins to check for conflicts & I have even tried reinstalling WordPress on the affected site with no success.

I am not sure of the cause of this problem (I saw somewhere that garbage code will display if the image code is taken straight from the database without ref to the image MIME type? Might that be happening here or is there an issue with the webhosting?).

I look forward to helpful replies

> > > > UPDATE EDIT<<<<

Just seen the cpanel error log:
[Fri Aug 19 14:29:10 2011] [error] [client 119.63.196.78] PHP Warning:  fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 123
[Fri Aug 19 14:29:10 2011] [error] [client 119.63.196.78] PHP Warning:  curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 112
[Fri Aug 19 14:29:10 2011] [error] [client 119.63.196.78] PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/upd100100.png) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 109
[Fri Aug 19 14:29:10 2011] [error] [client 119.63.196.78] PHP Warning:  fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 88
[Fri Aug 19 14:29:10 2011] [error] [client 119.63.196.78] PHP Warning:  curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 77
[Fri Aug 19 14:29:10 2011] [error] [client 119.63.196.78] PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCX100100.png) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 74
[Fri Aug 19 14:29:10 2011] [error] [client 119.63.196.78] PHP Warning:  fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 56
[Fri Aug 19 14:29:10 2011] [error] [client 119.63.196.78] PHP Warning:  fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 55
[Fri Aug 19 14:29:10 2011] [error] [client 119.63.196.78] PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/control.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 54
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:19 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 123, referer: http://exploreinternetmarketingonline.com/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.0/IBCX100100.png
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:19 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 123, referer: http://exploreinternetmarketingonline.com/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.0/IBCX100100.png
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:19 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 112, referer: http://exploreinternetmarketingonline.com/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.0/IBCX100100.png
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:19 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/upd100100.png) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 109, referer: http://exploreinternetmarketingonline.com/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.0/IBCX100100.png
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:19 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 88, referer: http://exploreinternetmarketingonline.com/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.0/IBCX100100.png
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:19 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 112, referer: http://exploreinternetmarketingonline.com/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.0/IBCX100100.png
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:19 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/upd100100.png) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 109, referer: http://exploreinternetmarketingonline.com/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.0/IBCX100100.png
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:19 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 88, referer: http://exploreinternetmarketingonline.com/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.0/IBCX100100.png
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:19 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 77, referer: http://exploreinternetmarketingonline.com/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.0/IBCX100100.png
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:19 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCX100100.png) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 74, referer: http://exploreinternetmarketingonline.com/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.0/IBCX100100.png
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:19 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 56, referer: http://exploreinternetmarketingonline.com/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.0/IBCX100100.png
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:19 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 55, referer: http://exploreinternetmarketingonline.com/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.0/IBCX100100.png
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:19 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/control.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 54, referer: http://exploreinternetmarketingonline.com/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.0/IBCX100100.png
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:19 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 77, referer: http://exploreinternetmarketingonline.com/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.0/IBCX100100.png
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:19 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCX100100.png) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 74, referer: http://exploreinternetmarketingonline.com/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.0/IBCX100100.png
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:19 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 56, referer: http://exploreinternetmarketingonline.com/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.0/IBCX100100.png
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:19 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 55, referer: http://exploreinternetmarketingonline.com/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.0/IBCX100100.png
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:19 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/control.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 54, referer: http://exploreinternetmarketingonline.com/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.0/IBCX100100.png
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:17 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 123
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:17 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 112
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:17 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/upd100100.png) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 109
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:17 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 88
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:17 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 77
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:17 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCX100100.png) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 74
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:17 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 56
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:17 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  fwrite(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 55
[Fri Aug 19 14:19:17 2011] [error] [client 74.104.34.167] PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/control.txt) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 54
[Fri Aug 19 14:17:15 2011] [error] [client 112.2.254.250] PHP Warning:  fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 123
[Fri Aug 19 14:17:15 2011] [error] [client 112.2.254.250] PHP Warning:  curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 112
[Fri Aug 19 14:17:15 2011] [error] [client 112.2.254.250] PHP Warning:  fopen(/home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/upd100100.png) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 109
[Fri Aug 19 14:17:15 2011] [error] [client 112.2.254.250] PHP Warning:  fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 88
[Fri Aug 19 14:17:15 2011] [error] [client 112.2.254.250] PHP Warning:  curl_setopt(): supplied argument is not a valid File-Handle resource in /home/eimo/public_html/wp-content/plugins/ibcxwizard_v1.02/IBCXwizard.php on line 77

(There is more! A large error log)

What does this mean-does it help to find a fix?

Comment: I have just looked at cpanel error logs & there is a ton of stuff relating to this plugin:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to fix without the source, but it appears your widget on the failing site is dumping the contents of the database out to the stream instead of generating a link to it. Either you aren't running the exact same widget code or there is some difference in the top-level Apache config that is causing an error in the widget output.

EDIT: Some configuration detail of the second server is off. The working server has this HTTP response header:

```
Server: Apache mod_fcgid/2.3.6 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635
```

The server that doesn't work has this HTTP response header:

```
Server: Apache/2.2.14 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.14 OpenSSL/0.9.7a mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635 PHP/5.2.10
```

Perhaps something that the plugin needs fails when not using `mod_fcgi`?

Comment: Hi Ferni-Thanks! That sounds like a fair diagnosis- Both sites are running the exact same plugin widget code so I expect it is some Apache server problem on the host server. Is there anyway I can test this & then contact the webhosting provider?

Comment: I had this advice>>it looks like the clients server is not allowing fopen to connect to the image. Make sure php allows this setting and the server is not in safe mode<< So I contacted the webserver & the reply is>>fopen works just fine on the server and also php is not in safe mode<<..short but not sweet-no further help given or offered! I have replied asking for some more help...

Comment: The clients webhoster refuses to deal with this and is advising the client to find hosting elsewhere! Amazing..poor service/support!